# How do I to properly relate objects in rails with out making separate tables for correlations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, schema

I am trying to figure out how to reduce the amount of tables / objects in my rails application. Here is an example of several objects and their relations. As of now there is no data, so I can edit these relations as needed. For this example there are 3 objects, Users, groups, and Rules

> Users
>      Relations
>        belongs_to_and_has_many Groups
>         belongs_to_and_has_many Rules
>
> Groups
>     Relations
>        #Used to have sub_groups
>         belongs_to_and_has_many Groups
>       belongs_to_and_has_many
>   Users
>          belongs_to_and_has_many Rules
>
> Rules
>      Relations
>        #Used to have sub_rules
>         belongs_to_and_has_many Rules  
>          belongs_to_and_has_many
>   Groups
>         belongs_to_and_has_many Users

Requirements: 
I don’t want to have tables for each of the relations.
A user may not have any groups or rules, or may have different rules depending on the group.
A group may not have any rules or may have several rules.
A rule may be part of only a group, user, or both.
Questions:

How do I store several groups in a rule object, in the groups field? 
    I don’t want to have a separate relational table for each relation because our system has 30 tables with a lot of these different scenarios of relations. There should be a way to store the relation in a array I just never have don’t that before and historically always created separate tables / objects for those kinds of relations.
Do I create and store the relations as an array? 
Would Rails know how to add / remove from there or would that be more on the GUI to remove / edit and just save the new array of objects on save?

Comment: Given the requirements you’ve identified the first step would likely be to have Rules use a polymorphic relationship to “subject” which could be either Group or User.

Comment: Reducing the amount of tables / objects is not always a good idea. Its better to have the right parts that do a single job well then cramming everything into a small set of god-objects. If you're designing your application from a "having too many classes is hard - waah" mindset instead of actually looking at the requirements and the SRP and how to make it extendable you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I didn't want to create a whole bunch of many-to-many tables either. So, here's how I do it (roughly).

I created a class called 'HasA' that looks something like:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: has_as
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  haser_type      :string           not null
#  haser_id        :integer          not null
#  hased_type:     :string           not null
#  hased_id:       :integer          not null
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
#
class HasA < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :haser_type, :haser_id, :hased_type, :hased_id, presence: true
  belongs_to :hased, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :haser, polymorphic: true
end
```

Then I created a module (actually, a collection of modules) that let me do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_having :groups, :rules
end
```

And

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_had_by :groups, :users
end
```

So that I can do things like:

```
@user.groups            
@user.groups << @group  
@user.groups.destroy(@group)
@user.group_ids
@user.groups.where(id: 4)
@user.groups.new(id: 5, name: 'foo')
```

And so on (essentially replicating many of the standard methods provided by `has_many`).

I can also do:

```
@rule.groups
@rule.users
```

Now, I can associate any models I want without having to have unique associations tables. There's just one `HasA` table that associates everything. And I can do all sorts of operations on the associated records without having to write any additional code. Which, I think, is what you're looking for.

Naturally, I bundled it all up as a gem so that I can include it in all my projects. 'Cause who wants to code something more than once?

Comment: Out of curiosity what does your index/es on the has_a table look like?

Comment: In the migration, I do something like: `add_index :haseds, [:hased_type, :hased_id]` and similar for `hasers`.